# Ember.js - How to avoid manually rendering templates

Tags: javascript, templates, ember.js, handlebars.js

I currently render my templates manually like so:

```
App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  renderTemplate: function() {
    this.render('index');
    this.render('nav', {
      outlet: 'nav',
      into  : 'index'
    });
    this.render('welcome', {
      outlet: 'welcome',
      into  : 'index'
    });
  }
});
```

Now this works fine, but its been brought to my attention that best ember practices avoid manually rendered templates.

So I can understand that my `index` template should and would be rendered automatically dude to Ember awesomeness. However, how do I control the rendering of my `nav` and `welcome` templates inside of my `index` template? Is that something I handle in the router, controller?  Or should I do it with handlebar partials?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

in the template where you have your outlets replace it with template renders

instead of

```
{{outlet nav}}
```

use

```
{{render 'nav'}}
```

and you can completely remove the render section for `nav`. After you've done the same for `welcome` you can delete the `renderTemplate` hook altogether.

Additionally, there is nothing wrong with using the `renderTemplate` hook, it's a very accepted practice, granted in your case unnecessary.

read more about the render helper here http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/rendering-with-helpers/#toc_the-code-render-code-helper